# Fragment Transaction Not working correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments

in my FragmnetActivity class i have Fragmnet Transaction with 3 fragmnet.
but my onclick metho its not working properly.it working for only one if and else condition.my other if condition not working.

what im doing wrong here..

```
public class Indi_Add_Details_menu extends FragmentActivity{

Fragment fragment;
Button btnFragment1, btnFragment2, btnFragment3, btnFragment4;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_detal_menu);
    btnFragment1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btnFragment2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btnFragment3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btnFragment4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);

    btnFragment1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_sbutton_pressed);
    btnFragment2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_tbutton_pressed);
    btnFragment3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_pbutton_pressed);
    btnFragment4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_button_pressed);

    // get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    //add a fragment
    Fragment_addStudentDetails myFragment = new Fragment_addStudentDetails();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    btnFragment1.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentOnClickListener);
    btnFragment2.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentOnClickListener);
    btnFragment3.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentOnClickListener);
    btnFragment4.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener btnFragmentOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Fragment newFragment;

        // Create new fragment
        if(v == btnFragment1){
            newFragment = new Fragment_addStudentDetails();

        }if(v == btnFragment2){
            newFragment = new Group_Add_test();

        }else{
            newFragment = new ExpandableListFragment();
        }

        // Create new transaction
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.myfragment, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }};
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    new DatePickerFragment((EditText) v).show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

}
```

when i add then Switch statement like this

```
 switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1:
                newFragment = new Fragment_addStudentDetails();
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                newFragment = new Group_Add_test();
                break;
            case R.id.btn3:
                newFragment = new ExpandableListFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

logcat say,

```
  Error:(80, 50) error: variable newFragment might not have been initialized
```

Comment: @rod-algonquin can you help me with this...

Comment: any error then please show logcat.

Comment: @silentkiller no error..app is running..but every time only working 2 butttons...
    if(v == btnFragment2){
            newFragment = new Group_Add_test();

        }else{
            newFragment = new ExpandableListFragment();
        }

these2 condition only

Comment: mean it is not going in else.?

Comment: @silentkiller no it going in else.but every time only one if and else conditon.ther if conditoin not working.also i trided with Switch statement..but then it say "newFragment" not initiating propery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Fragment newFragment;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1:
                newFragment = new Fragment_addStudentDetails();
                transaction.replace(R.id.myfragment, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                newFragment = new Group_Add_test();
                transaction.replace(R.id.myfragment, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.btn3:
                newFragment = new ExpandableListFragment();                  
                transaction.replace(R.id.myfragment, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code what I can make out is every time ***newFragment = new ExpandableListFragment();*** must have be executed.
The mistake you are doing in both condition check. ***if(v == btnFragment1)***....is not the right way to check the whether view was clicked or not....because it will be comparing the references.
**Solution** : ***if(v.getId() == btnFragment1.getId()){...***

Comment: but sttil it not working.

code is not executing this if contion

        if(v.getId() == R.id.btn1){
        newFragment = new Fragment_addStudentDetails();

" newFragment" variable naver use this error shows in there

Comment: initialize the newFragment as **e.g Fragment newFragment = new ExpandableListFragment();** before the switch also your switch/if condition snippet must be present before the fragment transaction snippet

Answer (score 0):

before switch case `Fragment newFragment;` initialize your fragment

Comment: i added your answer but..still it didnt fix..it say "  if(v.getId() == R.id.btn1){
        newFragment = new Fragment_addStudentDetails();  "   in here " newFragment" variable naver use

Comment: @rahulorry i didint understant it

Comment: had you use  transaction.replace(R.id.myfragment, newFragment);   
        transaction.commit(); else your it will not reflect

Comment: sorry sir..what do you mean there..?

Comment: try to remove the default case in switch, and if still same issue comes, try to print the v.getId(), and id of each view in log and show us.